How to prove the following fact about the epsilon net covering of the ball on $\mathbb{R}^n$?
For any $\epsilon>0$. Then there exist $y_1,\dots, y_m\in \mathbf{B}_2^n:=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n: \|x\|_2\le 1\}$ and a constant $c>0$ so that
$$
\mathbf{B}_2^n\subset \bigcup_{1\le i\le m} \left(y_i+\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{n}}\mathbf{B}_\infty^n\right)
$$
where $\mathbf{B}_\infty^n:=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n: \|x\|_\infty\le 1\}$.

To prove this result, we will use the following Lemma:

Let $R>0$. Then there exists a constant $C>0$ such that
$$
Card(\{x\in \mathbb{Z}^n: \|x\|_1\le R\})\le (\frac{CR}{n})^n
$$

I am confused about the proof of the main result:

Let $R=\frac{n}{\epsilon}$. Then by the above Lemma there exists $c>0$ and $y_1,\dots, y_m \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ with $\|y_i\|_1\le R$, where $m\le (C/\epsilon)^n$.

(1) How do we have
$$
\frac{R}{\sqrt{n}} \mathbf{B}_2^n\subset \bigcup_{1\le i\le m}(y_i+\mathbf{B}_\infty^n)?
$$

Now, by excluding those $y_i$ lie outside a ball of radius $\frac{3R}{2\sqrt{n}}$ and by re-indexing if necessary we may choose $y_1,\dots, y_{m'}\in \frac{3R}{2\sqrt{n}}\mathbf{B}_2^n\cap \{y_1,\dots, y_m\}$ such that
$$
\frac{R}{\sqrt{n}} \mathbf{B}_2^n\subset \bigcup_{1\le i\le m'}(y_i+\mathbf{B}_\infty^n).
$$

(2) How do we have
$$
 \mathbf{B}_2^n\subset \bigcup_{1\le i\le m'}(\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{n}}y_i+\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{n}}\mathbf{B}_\infty^n)?
$$
(Multiply $\sqrt{n}/R$ on both side?)
(3) Also, why do we have $\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{n}}y_i\in \mathbf{B}_2^n$?
I check that
$$
\|\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{n}}y_i\|_2=\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{n}}\|y_i\|_2\le \frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{n}}\|y_i\|_1\le \frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{n}} R=\sqrt{n}?
$$

Define $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{Z}$ by $$g(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} \max\{q\in\mathbb{Z}:q\leqslant x\} & : x \geqslant 0 \\ \min\{q\in \mathbb{Z} : q\geqslant x\} & : x < 0.\end{array}\right.$$ Note that $|g(x)|\leqslant |x|$ ald $|g(x)-x|<1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.
Define $G:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{Z}^n$ by $$G(x_1,\ldots, x_n)=(g(x_1),\ldots, g(x_n)).$$ By the above properties of $g$, $$\|G(x)\|_1\leqslant \|x\|_1,$$ $$\|G(x)\|_2\leqslant \|x\|_2,$$ and $$\|g(x)-x\|_\infty<1$$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$.
Fix $\epsilon>0$ and let $R=n/\epsilon$. Let $$L=\{x\in \mathbb{Z}^n:\|x\|_1\leqslant R\}.$$
Recall that By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, with $y=(1,1,\ldots,1)\in\mathbb{R}^n$, for any $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, $$\|x\|_1=\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i| = \sum_{i=1}^n 1\cdot |x_i|\leqslant \|y\|_2\|x\|_2=\sqrt{n}\|x\|_2.$$
Therefore if $x\in \frac{R}{\sqrt{n}}B^n_2$, $$\|G(x)\|_1\leqslant R,$$ and so $G(x)\in L$.   Let $y_1,\ldots, y_m$ be some enumeration of $$\Bigl\{G(x):x\in \frac{R}{\sqrt{n}}B^n_2\Bigr\},$$ which is a subset of $L$, and therefore we have $$m\leqslant |L|\leqslant (C/\epsilon)^n.$$ Equivalently, $y_1,\ldots, y_m$ is an enumeration of $$\frac{R}{\sqrt{n}}B^n_2\cap L,$$ since a member $y$ of $L$ is a member of $\frac{R}{\sqrt{n}}B^n_2$ if and only if it is $y=G(x)$ for some $x\in \frac{R}{\sqrt{n}}B^n_2$.   It is important here that we did not take all of $L$ for our $y_i$. We only take those members of $L$ which are images of some $x\in \frac{R}{\sqrt{n}}B^n_2$ under $G$.  This answers the last question: Each $y_i$ has $\|y_i\|_2\leqslant R/\sqrt{n}=\sqrt{n}/{\epsilon}$ by choice. So $$\Bigl\|\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{n}}y_i\Bigr\|_2\leqslant \frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{n}}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\epsilon}=1.$$
We already know that $\|G(x)-x\|_\infty<1$ for any $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, so for any $x\in \frac{R}{\sqrt{n}}B^n_2$, $$x\in G(x)+B^n_\infty\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^m y_i + B^n_\infty.$$ This gives the first question.
For the second question: Yes. If $x\in B^n_2$, then $$x':=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\epsilon}x=\frac{R}{\sqrt{n}}x,$$ and $G(x')=y_j$ for some $1\leqslant j\leqslant m$.  Then $$x'=y_j+z$$ for some $z\in B^n_\infty$, and $$x=\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{n}}x'=\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{n}}y_j+\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{n}}z\in \bigcup_{i=1}^m \frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{n}}y_i+\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{n}}B^n_\infty.$$
